# Why is $\delta U$ not zero in $\delta H = \delta U + \delta(PV)$ while defining at a constant temperature for an ideal gas?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, ideal-gas

I was studying thermodynamics and came across the relation between change in internal energy and the change in enthalpy for an IDEAL gas, meaning $U=f(T)$ and not $f(T,V)$.
Then, while defining it for an ideal gas at a constant temperature, my textbook says that the relation is given by
$\delta H = \delta U + RT\,\delta n$, $n$ stands for no of gaseous moles.
My doubt is, while defining this at a constant temperature, why is $\delta U$ not taken as zero for an ideal gas..??  (kindly ignore the sign conventions)

Answer (score 2):

The internal energy of an ideal gas with $f$ degrees of freedom is $U = \frac{f}{2}nRT$. Under the assumption that $n$ is constant we can say that $U = U(T)$. However in your problem the number of moles is changing so we have to consider that $U = U(n,T)$ and so
$$\mathrm dU = \frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\mathrm dT + \frac{\partial U}{\partial n}\mathrm dn$$
The partial derivative with respect to $n$ is $\frac{\partial U}{\partial n} = \frac{f}{2}RT$ and $T$ is constant so with a change of moles $\Delta n$ you get
$$\Delta U = \frac{f}{2}RT\Delta n$$
So the problem was simply that the expression from your textbook "$U = f(T)$" was derived using assumptions that are not true in this specific application.

Answer (score 2):

Your reference is describing an ideal gas mixture, not a single molecular species, which is undergoing a chemical reaction (presumably at constant temperature).  For a gas mixture, the internal energy is a function no only of temperature and pressure, but also the chemical makeup of the mixture.  If the mole fractions of the various species in the mixture change due to chemical reaction, the internal energy changes, even at constant temperature and pressure.